# A little doubt about set notation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is $ A \setminus B = A \setminus (A \cap {B})$.

I am learning sets and it is given that A minus B is {x $\in$ A such that x $\notin$ B}. Is it the same as A minus A intersection B. One word answer will do if "yes"; explain if "no".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is a true statement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is: $A\setminus B=A\setminus (A\cap B)$.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that is correct. And here are some extra characters to make the answer long enough.

Comment: A handy trick I've seen some people use to pad out their answers is putting {}{}{}{}... in between dollar signs.